# Contrasting outcomes when downloading Maven artifact from Azure Artifacts using REST API in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-artifacts

I am running the below script in a Powershell ISE console to download a Maven package from our Azure Artifacts repository and and it works perfectly, downloading the war file to my local directory successfully.

**Run in Powershell ISE**

```
$url = 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organisation}/{project}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedID}/maven/{groupID/{artifactID}/{version}/{filename}/content?api-version=6.1-preview.1'

$connectionToken="my-personal-access-token"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$buildPipeline= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -OutFile .\xxx-portal-18.29.06.war -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get
```

However, when I run the same script (albeit with a different output directory) from an Azure Pipelines Powershell Task as depicted below, it fails miserably. The error written to the Pipeline log appears to suggest the failure is down to an authentication issue. What could I be doing wrong and am I using the correct authentication method?

**Run as an Azure Pipelines Powershell Task**

```
$url = 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organisation}/{project}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedID}/maven/{groupID/{artifactID}/{version}/{filename}/content?api-version=6.1-preview.1'

$connectionToken="my-personal-access-token"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$buildPipeline= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Outfile $(Build.BinariesDirectory)\xxx-broker-portal-18.29.06.war -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get
```

Answer (score 0):

We create a new [Project-scoped](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Fconcepts%2Ffeeds%3Fview%3Dazure-devops%23project-scoped-feeds-vs-organization-scoped-feeds&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cc76ba6d5bd634a22bf4e08d8be8e2e01%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637468865157455551%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=88HUqfzpUNUI4EaMJZbLpNrWPHpfT%2Buo%2FlnycEv0mU0%3D&reserved=0) maven feed and follow this blog: [Maven Package Management with Visual Studio Team Services](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.azuredevopslabs.com%2Flabs%2Fjava%2Fmavenpmvsts%2F&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cc76ba6d5bd634a22bf4e08d8be8e2e01%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637468865157455551%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=2ZsgY7RNuWkbitIFvh4XEji5FHg80N3kF3l%2BNgbZwQI%3D&reserved=0) to publish a maven package. And then using this API: [Maven - Download Package](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Frest%2Fapi%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifactspackagetypes%2Fmaven%2Fdownloadpackage%3Fview%3Dazure-devops-rest-6.0&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cc76ba6d5bd634a22bf4e08d8be8e2e01%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637468865157465551%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=6Hy7Tdstt1XHWt41vtBTPRGB0rLkvjazfmJbWPgUOHE%3D&reserved=0) to download below war file with your provided PowerShell script.
[image]
And we run the same script (albeit with a different output directory) from an Azure Pipelines [PowerShell Task](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fpipelines%2Ftasks%2Futility%2Fpowershell%3Fview%3Dazure-devops&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cc76ba6d5bd634a22bf4e08d8be8e2e01%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637468865157475547%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=Ee4vB304qg9CNBXFi5ElQDJZ2J44mLYs5nkbeMr7hXU%3D&reserved=0), all work as expected.

Please check if you have proper permissions to write *xxx-broker-portal-18.29.06.war* file to target directory: **$(Build.BinariesDirectory)**. If you own the administrator role for this private agent and can manage directories(*Read, write, & manage*) where this agent located in, this error should not occur.